# Android - Store variable and use in webview link

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store the users input from a text field in shared preferences and use that input in a webview link.

Here's what I have so far;

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

EditText subdomain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    subdomain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subdomain);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
MainActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

public void saveInfo (View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("spfile", 
Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("name", YourSchool.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a 
browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Use remote resource

mWebView.loadUrl("https://"+client_subdomain+".domain.co.uk/texts");

    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead 
of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());


}
public void displayData (View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("spfile", 
Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String client_subdomain = sharedPref.getString("name", "");
}

// Prevent the back-button from closing the app
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.app.LoginActivity">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/YourSchool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Your school"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="webView"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the 
user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My problem is that the client_subdomain is flagged as red in the MainActivity.java and when I try to build the project, I get the error: cannot find symbol variable client_subdomain

I think it's probably something small that I've missed out but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Sam

Comment: Store the user input in `SQLite` or `SharedPreferences`. Retrieve the stored value and use in `loadUrl`

Comment: String extraInfo="foo";
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://"+extraInfo+".mydomain.co.uk");

So what's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Store the variable using sharedPrefeence as below,

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("your_string_key", yourStringValue);
editor.commit();
```

Then retrieve the value as,

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String myStringValue = sp.getInt("your_string_key", -1);
```

Use the variable in the `loadUrl` as

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://"+myStringValue+".mydomain.co.uk");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's helped so far but I'm a little stuck so I've modified by opening question. Would you mind helping please?

Comment: you have declared client_subdomain as a local variable for the method displaydata. Declare the variable inside the class.

Comment: Before onCreate(),    private WebView mWebView;
private  String client_subdomain;